# Join and count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables; let's call them TableA and TableB. Each element of TableB is associated with an element of TableA in a many-to-one relationship. Some elements of TableA may have no corresponding element in TableB.

I need to select every element in TableA, along with a column that will, for each row in the result set, contain the number of elements in TableB that are associated with that row in TableA, and that have a certain property.

Using MS SQL Server 2008 (Needs to also work in SQL Server 2005).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated**

```
SELECT A.elementid, A.column1, A.column2, A.column3, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN B.someColumn > 0 THEN B.elementid ELSE NULL END) Q
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON A.elementid = B.elementid
GROUP BY A.elementid, A.column1, A.column2, A.column3
```

Comment: I need to only get the number of elements of B that are associated with each row of A, *and that satisfy a certain property*. For concreteness, let's say this property is "B.someColumn > 0"

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN B.someColumn > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) or COUNT(CASE WHEN B.someColumn > 0 THEN B.elementid ELSE NULL END) may be clearer.

Comment: I agree with gbn. Code reviewers will thank you, when you always supply the else path to your case ... when ... **else** statements

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TableA.MyColumn, COUNT(TableB.SomeColumn) AS MyCount
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.TableAKeyColumn = TableB.TableAKeyColumn
GROUP BY TableA.MyColumn
```

Comment: Please see my comment on the above answer.

Comment: @Brennan Vincent the order of answers doesn't reflect the order in which they where entered, just like rows in SQL Table